# R - Using par() to create a grid of ggplot plots - Not working as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data that looks like this

```
# Generate example data
exampleData <- data.frame(Month = sample(1:5, 500, replace = T),
                          Product = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 500, replace = T),
                          Site = sample(letters[1:5], 500, replace = T),
                          Used = sample(1:100, 500, replace = T))
exampleData <- aggregate(. ~ Month + Product + Site, data = exampleData, sum)      # Consolidating any duplicates
exampleData <- exampleData[order(exampleData$Month, exampleData$Product, exampleData$Site, exampleData$Used),]
```

I wanted to see trends in different products at different sites, so created this function

```
# Funciton to retrieve info about a product and site
productSiteInfo <- function(p, s) {
  return(exampleData[intersect(which(exampleData$Product == p), which(exampleData$Site == s)),])
}
```

To make my comparisons easier, I want to make a grid of line plots, where the grid consits of plots of a specific product at all the sites. So I tried this code

```
# Plotting the data
prods <- unique(exampleData$Product)  # All products
prod <- sample(prods,1)      # Select a product of interest
sites <- unique(exampleData$Site)     # All sites
par(mfrow=c(3,2))       # Create grid
lapply(head(sites), function(site) {      # Plot trend of prod at all sites
  aDF <- productSiteInfo(prod, site)
  ggplot() +
           geom_line(data = aDF, aes(x = Month, y = Used), color = "black") +
           xlab("Month") +
           ylab("Units") + 
           ggtitle(paste("Consumption of", prod, "at", site))
})
```

But it's not working as expected. I'm not getting a grid of plots, but just individual plots. I was wondering why that was, and what I can do to get that grid. My actual data has ~10 products and ~160 sites, so it's gonna be much larger than this example.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `par(mfrow=...)` is only compatible with base graphics, not with anything `grid`-based (e.g., `lattice`, `ggplot2`). If you want to combine, you can try `gridExtra::grid.arrange` or the `cowplot` package. Another option would be to use `ggplot::facet_*` if the data is compatible.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the tip. I ended up saving my lapply to a variable lst, and tried arranging the plots in lst with grid.extra. But it looks like it'll only work if I do `grid.arrange(lst[[1]], lst[[2]], lst[[3]], lst[[4]], lst[[5]], ncol = 3)`, which isn't really feasible since I have ~160 plots. I don't want to write out all 160 arguments in the above function. Do you know how I can arrange them with grid.arrange wihtout having to write out ever ysingle plot parameter? Thanks

Comment: oh, now I see the 160 and how my answer may not be perfectly suited ... Oliver's answer likely is much closer than mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reason why this doesn't work, is that `ggplot` doesn't adhere to rules of standard plots.
Usually creating multiple plots in a grid is done using `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` where you use an existing variable within your data to split the dataset into multiple plots. This approach is definitely recommended if your grouping variable resides within your data.

@r2evans suggested using `grid.extra` which is also a classic approach to arrange **any** given series of plots into subsections (similar to `cowplot`).
However for what I'd call the *ultimate* convenience I'd suggest using [`patchwork`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/patchwork/index.html) and checking out their short well written guides. For your specific example it can be as simple as adding the plots together.

```
plots <- lapply(head(sites), function(site) {      # Plot trend of prod at all sites
  aDF <- productSiteInfo(prod, site)
  ggplot() +
           geom_line(data = aDF, aes(x = Month, y = Used), color = "black") +
           xlab("Month") +
           ylab("Units") + 
           ggtitle(paste("Consumption of", prod, "at", site))
})
library(patchwork)
library(purrr) #for reduce
reduce(plots, `+`)
```

[image]
As you note here I simply *add* together the plots, while I could use `-` to remove plots `/` to arrange plots above each other and so forth.

Comment: I "second" the recommendation for `patchwork`, I'd forgotten that in my comment.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this view using facets:

```r
set.seed(42)
exampleData <- data.frame(Month = sample(1:5, 500, replace = T),
                          Product = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 500, replace = T),
                          Site = sample(letters[1:5], 500, replace = T),
                          Used = sample(1:100, 500, replace = T))
exampleData <- aggregate(. ~ Month + Product + Site, data = exampleData, sum)      # Consolidating any duplicates
exampleData <- exampleData[order(exampleData$Month, exampleData$Product, exampleData$Site, exampleData$Used),]

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = exampleData, aes(x = Month, y = Used, color = Product)) +
  facet_wrap("Site", nrow=3, ncol=2,
             labeller = labeller(Site = function(x) paste("Site", x))) +
  xlab("Month") +
  ylab("Units")
```

[image: ggplot2, faceted with color-grouped product lines]

Changes made:

- started with `set.seed(42)` so that we all have the same data :-) ;
- use the whole data, no need to `lapply` across it;
- added `color=Product` as an aesthetic, so that (1) the lines would be grouped correctly, but more importantly (2) your label of "product x on site y" would be discernible (and comparable between facets);
- added `facet_wrap` with a `labeller` function to prepend `Site` to each label header; and
- removed `ggtitle` since the label headers do the same thing.

Comment: While not perfectly relevant for this question, I'll keep the answer for others with smaller datasets and who still think `par(mfrow=)` is an option.